# Google Analytics in Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a problem. I connect Google Analytics to a chrome extension and get an error (Service worker registration failed). Help me please.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
},
  "icons": {
    "128": "logo.png"
},
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage"]
}
```

background.js

```
((i, s, o, g, r, a, m) => {
  i.GoogleAnalyticsObject = r;
  (i[r] = i[r] || function () {
  (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
   }),
  (i[r].l = 1 * new Date());
 (a = s.createElement(o)), (m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]);
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
 })(
   window,
  document,
  "script",
  "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js",
  "ga"
   );

   window.ga("create", "UA-XXXXX-X", "auto");
   window.ga("set", "checkProtocolTask", () => {});
   window.ga("require", "displayfeatures");
   window.ga("send", "pageview", "/background.html");
```

Comment: It won't work in ManifestV3 background script. See https://crbug.com/1164452

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks. There are working examples of google analytics for manifest v3?

Answer (score -1):

I copied https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js to js file and imported it to my project. Also I hade to disable eslint and tslint for this file. like this:

```
    /* @tslint-nocheck */
    /* eslint-disable */
    export default function runAnalytics() {
      //here goes code of your analytics.js file
    }
```